# How to make PyCharm Javascript auto imports work correctly?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, pycharm

Up until recently PyCharm would automatically add node_modules import statements like:

```js
import { useRef } from 'react';
```

now suddenly the only option it gives is this import

```js
import { useRef } from 'react/cjs/react.production.min';
```

I've tried looking through the relevant preferences but have no idea what could be wrong. What settings have changed in recent updates that broke this?

Comment: can't reproduce. Do you have react typings (`@types/react`) installed? I'd also suggest adding `react/cjs/` to **Do not import exactly from** list in **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript** and re-opening the project - does it make things any better?

Comment: Thank you @lena, adding `react/*` to "Do not import exactly from" fixed the problem! Wonder if that used to be a default but now it's not anymore.